# Java's keytool doesn't prompt for key password

Tags: java, passwords, keystore, prompt, keytool

Java's `keytool` has a parameter called `-keypass` which allows you to set a (separate) password to protect your private key, in addition to the password used for the entire key store.

According to the documentation:

> The value of `-keypass` is a password used to protect the private key of the generated key pair. If a password is not provided, then the user is prompted for it. If you press the Return key at the prompt, then the key password is set to the same password as the keystore password. The `-keypass` value must have at least six characters.

However, when I leave out the password in the call to this command I don't seem to get prompted at all, at least not when this is used in combination with `-genkeypair` to generate an RSA key pair. Instead I just get the general help page. If I use `""` to force an "empty" password then it (correctly) tells me that the password should at least be 6 characters.

Is there a way to force the `keytool` to prompt for a key specific password instead of having to offer it on the command line according to the documentation of `-genkeypair`?

---

I've tested this against Java 11 LTS:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias test1 -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keystore test.pfx -storepass test1234
        -keypass
```

or

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias test1 -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keystore test.pfx -storepass test1234
        -keypass ""
```

both don't seem to work; as you can see I've already moved the `-keypass` parameter to the end so it cannot gobble up a parameter as password.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default keystore type for Java 11 is `PKCS12`, for which it is always assumed the keystore password and key password will be the same, hence you are not prompted to enter it ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html))

If you need to use a key password to fit your requirements, you can use other keystore types like `jks` or `jceks`.

Note: If you are using jks or jceks, java will show you a warning message:

> The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format

---

If you type:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore double.pfx -storepass Storepass -keypass Keypass
```

You'll get the following warning:

```
Warning:  Different store and key passwords not supported for PKCS12 KeyStores.
```

---

Note that the PKCS#12 key stores themselves **do** support multiple passwords: they have separate derivations for multiple sections (keys, certificates) and `KeyBag`'s and such. It's just that the Java support is missing. I found this out after parsing several key stores and looking at the format.

Comment: The documentation doesn't explicitly state it, but there is a statement in the documentation stating `Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the following standard KeyStore type PKCS#12` and also a [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/jdk9-keytool-transitions-default-keystore-to-pkcs12) mentioning this.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but why do you think that PKCS#12 doesn't allow you to set a separate password for a key?

Comment: I guess it is a non-written standard for the PKCS#12. I know this is not a concrete answer but the best I could find is in the Java's keytool [document](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html), which says - `For example, most third-party tools require storepass and keypass in a PKCS #12 keystore to be the same. To create a PKCS#12 keystore for these tools, always specify a -destkeypass that is the same as -deststorepass.`

Comment: Hmm, tried two different passwords and got the result you alluded to. Unexpected to say the least as the inner PKCS8ShroudedKeyBag should support a separate password, it even performs a separate key derivation for it. But yeah, I cannot argue against that warning... Thanks for your help, it made me have another look to see that you are right.

Comment: Not only third-party tools. Java itself doesn't support key passwords via the JSSE system properties. You have to initialize your own `SSLContext` and `KeyManager` and so forth to support that. It's really quite difficult.